# Some man pages not found

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, man, manpages

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.  I had Fedora a couple of years back and I saw the man pages for the following there:

```
unistd.h,
sys/types.h,     
standard typedefs (suffixed by "_t") etc.
```

I tried this:

```
man unistd
```

But it didn't find it.

I think those pages are not there in Ubuntu.

Although `man stdio` works and other man pages are there.

So

- If Ubuntu doesn't have those pages, please tell me how to download them
- And what is the command for viewing standard typedef man page i.e. man page for `size_t`, `pid_t`, `off_t`, `clock_t` etc.

I tried `man stddef` but it says "command not found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what needed to do...

`sudo apt-get install manpages-posix-dev`

to get those pages :)